# Возможно отправить get запрос без сторонних библиотек используя лишь чистый Android Studio?

Tags: android

Возможно отправить get запрос без сторонних библиотек используя лишь чистый Android Studio?

Comment: sdk в любом случае нужно будет устанавливать, так что нет, нельзя.

Comment: господи, ну такую-то хрень в гугле найти можно даже на за 10, а за 3 секунды. Вы издеваетесь?

Comment: Что значит "чистый"? Так понимаю, отсутствие импорта, как минимум, JAR-пакетов. Ну, в таком случае в чем заключается суть вопроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вопрос связан с написанием Android приложения и задача состоит в отправке GET запроса из приложения без сторонних библиотек, то самым простым решением будет

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        String responseString = out.toString();
        out.close();
    } else{
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }
```